# DS3231 module li-ion charging circuit tweak

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, charge, over-voltage-protection, voltage

Most of the DS3231 modules come with a "charging" circuit for a LIR2032 battery. I understand that, as-is, it's considered garbage.

The reason people say not to use the module as-is is due to the charging voltage. If you have a perfect 5v source and a perfect 1n4148 diode, then the theoretical drop across the diode is generally stated to be around 0.8v so it sends 4.2 to the battery. But if the current load on the diode is very low, such as when the battery is almost fully charged, the drop on the diode can go down (around 0.4-0.5v for a load of 0.1ma in the datasheet at https://www.vishay.com/docs/81857/1n4148.pdf. It's actually showing maybe 0.7 at 10ma and 0.5 at 0.1ma), thus making the voltage across the battery go way above the safe 4.2v limit (and I'm ignoring the possibility of the power supply being higher than 5v, making it even worse. That's not really relevant to the question as asked.)

I have plans to cut away the trace and wire in a real battery-charging module but I'm curious as to a "cheap-man's fix" and if the following would even work at all.

If the diode could go to as low as 0.4-0.5v drop at extremely low currents, then having two in series would give a total 0.8-1.0v drop, right? Thus two would still be within safe limits of the <=4.2v. And having two in series would go up to 1.4-1.6v drop at higher current flow (again, assuming typical values. And yes, I know that "typical" usually means "this is what the **OTHER** guy always gets. You, being the loser you are, get the extremes and that's why things never work as expected.")

So my thinking is that if the battery is at 0%, the current flow may be around 15-20ma and the voltage may be around 3.4-3.6v. This would barely even charge the battery. But as the battery slowly builds up charge closer to the charging voltage, the current flow drops and the voltage drop on the diodes goes down so the voltage fed to the battery goes up. It seems like it'd be a self-correcting system, even if a very inefficient one, where the higher the charge on the battery, the lower the voltage drop on the diode and the lower the current flow, basically balancing out and not changing at some point. Maybe it stops at 50% of capacity or at 80%, etc. and never fully charges. But the main thing is "would the balancing point come before the system got to the 4.2v level?" and it seems that it would.

I'm just wondering if my logic is anywhere even close to correct (or maybe the resulting charge curve would kill the battery even faster?)

Comment: A "poor man's" Li-ion battery charger is not something anyone should be using. A proper charger will shut off completely when the battery is charged and avoid damaging it, and maybe you.

Comment: Remove the charging circuit and just use a standard CR2032 cell. Should last for years.

Comment: I realize that this idea isn't the best way to charge an Li-ion battery. I realize that you can disable the charging circuit and use a regular battery. I'm simply wondering if the self-feedback of such a circuit would work as described or is there some reason that it won't.

Just like "can you put a jato on a car and make it move?"